# Typescript: Extend type definitions for external package (deck.gl)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, deck.gl

I'm trying to extend two type definitions from an external package ([deck.gl](https://deck.gl/docs), with typings [here](https://github.com/danmarshall/deckgl-typings)) and having no success so far.

I have a `types` directory in my project and this `deckgl.d.ts` file, to import the separate typings library, which works as expected:

```
import * as DeckTypings from '@danmarshall/deckgl-typings';
declare module 'deck.gl' {
    export namespace DeckTypings {}
}
```

There are two things I want to extend: an interface and a class.

1. For the interface, I want to update the definition of interface `DeckProps`, changing only the `viewState` attribute. I've tried handling it like this (adding to `deckgl.d.ts`):

```
declare module '@deck.gl/core/lib/deck' {
    import { ViewStateProps } from '@deck.gl/core/views/view';
    export interface DeckProps {
        viewState: ViewStateProps | { [key: string]: ViewStateProps };
    }
}
```

2. The class I want to update is `MapView`, allowing it to be used like a JSX element. I've done this, following the example of the [typings library itself](https://github.com/danmarshall/deckgl-typings/blob/c916639d5dbe7f59739501df5d6dd5363399194c/deck.gl__react/index.d.ts#L61), also adding to `deckgl.d.ts`:

```
declare module '@deck.gl/core/views/map-view' {
    import React from 'react';
    import { ViewProps } from '@deck.gl/core/views/view';
    export type MapViewProps = Partial<ViewProps>;
    export default class MapView extends React.Component<MapViewProps> {
        constructor(props?: MapViewProps);
        equals(view: any): any;
        makeViewport({ width, height, viewState }: { width: any; height: any; viewState: any }): any;
        getViewStateId(): any;
        filterViewState(viewState: any): any;
        getDimensions({ width, height }: { width: any; height: any }): {
            x: any;
            y: any;
            width: any;
            height: any;
        };
        _getControllerProps(defaultOpts: any): any;
        _getViewport(props: any): any;
        _parseDimensions({ x, y, width, height }: { x: any; y: any; width: any; height: any }): void;
    }
}
```

The strange thing, is that it seems like *sometimes* the ts compiler is aware of these definitions - VS code suddenly shows no errors and running `tsc` in the command line shows no errors either. But whether or not it works (shows no ts errors) seems to be totally independent of the state of the code.

Could there be something changing in the order ts compiles things? Or is there something else I should be doing differently?

Comment: If the deck.gl types are truly only working _sometimes_, there might be another dependency in your project that is overwriting the deck.gl types.

When this happens to me, usually after installing another dependency, I do this to "fix": `(cd node_modules/@danmarshall/deckgl-typings && yarn install)`, which essentially forces the danmarshall types to be installed.

If that works for you, you can put it in your post-install scripts, or just do like I do and run it whenever the types appear to be messed up.

You might also have some success with `yarn install --force`.

Answer (score 2):

In situations when your own extensions to the types stop working, are the base types from `@danmarshall/deckgl-typings` recognised at all, or no?

**Probable cause**

There is actually a problem with the unofficial typings package for Deck.GL due to how it's not currently release through the `@types` namespace on npm. Rather, it uses https://github.com/danmarshall/indefinitely-typed to copy the work-in-progress types to the `node_modules/@types` directory. However, there's a problem with npm when any new package is installed - the manually copied deck typings are deleted from `node_modules`.

To me it sounds that if your types suddenly stop working, it's because the underlying types, which you're extending, are lost.

**Workaround**

A workaround I've used in the past that doesn't rely on `indefinitely-typed` but rather simply on tsconfig, is to add the `deckgl-typings` package directly to TypeScript's type resolution paths.

Assuming you're using CRA, you need to create a separate tsconfig and extend it (because `react-scripts` annoyingly overwrites the `paths` value in the main tsconfig).

Given a directory structure:

```
src/
node_modules/
tsconfig.json
```

Create a `tsconfig-typings.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "./node_modules/@danmarshall/deckgl-typings/*",
        "*"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Then, in the main `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
"extends": "./tsconfig-typings.json",
//...
}
```

If you're not using CRA, just include the `baseUrl` and `paths` options inside `compilerOptions` of the main `tsconfig.json`

This workaround make TS always find the types, so they don't disappear every once in a while when you install another package.

A more manual workaround is to always `npm install -D @danmarshall/deckgl-typings` after you install another package...